# pactl package in docker alpine container

Tags: docker, pulseaudio, alpine-linux

I want to `pactl` in a docker Alpine container. I installed pulseaudio and also tried `apk add pactl`. How can I install pactl under Docker Alpine container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pactl` can be installed on Alpine Linux through:

```
apk add pulseaudio-utils
```

Contents of [pulseaudio-utils](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=pulseaudio-utils&branch=v3.15&repo=community&arch=x86_64)